# Display content from custom meta boxes in revisions

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

When I see a "revision" for a given post type, I only see the title, the content and the excerpt. How can I see the content of a custom meta box (or any other field, for that matter)?

Comment: This guy gives an answer... http://lud.icro.us/post-meta-revisions-wordpress/

Comment: The link above is broken

Answer (score 1):

Custom meta isn't attached to revisions - only to the parent post, so there are no revisions for it.
You can do it manually by grabbing the post meta from the parent though.